# snowflake procedure syntax error while querying information schema

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, database-cursor

Idea is I am trying to query information schema metadata and build columns based on datatypes if  date then I create min date max date ,if number then check count of distinct or count rows

I have simplified now I will pass dbname , schema name and table name as parameters,

My output should return with below columns
SCHEMA_NM,TBL_NAME,_COUNT,_DISTINCT_COUNT,_MIN_DATE,_MAX_DATE.

For testing purpose at least if two measure is syntactically correct remaining I will take care

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE PROFILING( DB_NAME VARCHAR(16777216),TBL_SCHEMA VARCHAR(16777216), TBL_NAME VARCHAR(16777216))
RETURNS VARCHAR(16777216)
LANGUAGE SQL
EXECUTE AS CALLER
AS 
$$
DECLARE
BEGIN
    create or replace temporary table tbl_name as (select case when data_type=NUMBER then (execute immediate 'select count(col_val) from ' || :1 || '.' ||  :2 || '.' ||  :3) else null end as col_value_num,case when data_type=DATE then (execute immediate 'select count(col_val) from ' || :1 || '.' ||  :2 || '.' ||  :3) else null end as col_min_date from   ':1.information_schema.columns where table_catalog=:1 and table_schema=:2 and table_name=:3 ' )) ;
     insert into some_base_table as select * from tbl_name;
     truncate tbl_name 
RETURN 'SUCCESS';
END;
$$;
```

With above query I am getting below error

```
 error : SQL compilation error: Invalid expression value (?SqlExecuteImmediateDynamic?) for assignment.
```

Any help here please

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple errors in your code, but the error you mentioned is about this line:

```
num := (execute immediate "select count(col_val) from tab_cat.tab_schema.tab_name") ;
```

NUM is declared as integer, you can't directly assign a value from execute immediate. Execute immediate statement returns a resultset. To access the value you need to define a cursor and fetch the data.

The SQL should be surrounded by single quotes (not double quotes), and you should also build the string correctly. Something like this:

```
result := (execute immediate 'select count(col_val) from ' || tab_cat || '.' ||  tab_schema || '.' ||  tab_name ) ;
```

Comment: I am still getting the error SQL compilation error: Invalid expression value (?SqlExecuteImmediateDynamic?) for assignment.

Comment: @NaveenSrikanth can you update your question with the "fixed" code?

Comment: I have modified the title logic , can you please check now

Comment: @NaveenSrikanth you can't use execute immediate as a subquery. You also used bind variables without stating. Column_name is also missing. Anyway I wrote a working version but it fails with Unsupported subquery type cannot be evaluated. You should restructure the SP.

Comment: can you please post whatever you have done . I will try to modify and make it work . In my query count(col_val) is actualy count(column_name). This column_name will come from information schema

Comment: I am not sure how else I should restructure this. Tried with cursor loop it was tedious . Then I thought will put in this way . It is also going difficult . My idea is to profile attributes from information schema with count, min, max and store in a table. Just struggling to get one syntax

Comment: Any luck please ?